# How can I make permeable landscaping cloth drain better?

Tags: landscaping

I got some synthetic grass for the dogs to play on. We put down landscaping cloth which is black with blue lines about every foot. The cloth was laid down, but we noticed that the dog pee didn't drain through it.  How is this "permeable".  What should I do to this cloth before I put the synthetic grass on top of it?  Underneath the cloth is soil, and the whole yard slopes about 30 degrees downhill right up against our house.  Will be a BIG problem when rain comes...should we aerate the cloth? Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

Geotextile weed membrane is intended for use beneath open soil or mulch, with heavier duty types being used beneath paved areas.

Artificial lawn is always laid on to either crushed aggregate, tamped down, or tamped aggregate with sand on top, again tamped down, depending on the situation (sports ground, home lawn) and the product supplied (suppliers' instructions). The lawn is then laid directly on top of that, and it drains into the sand/aggregate base. A little more slowly than ordinary grass, but it does drain. There should be no membrane beneath - as you have a membrane, you will inevitably have serious drainage problems when it's wet.

Suggest you take up the lawn, remove the membrane, lay a proper base appropriate for the product you have, and replace.